# Live Preview PHP Project

Tags: php, macos, sublimetext3, text-editor

I would like to configure my PHP development environment to live preview. I have researched about it and the only result i got is using brackets text editor. But, I am using Sublime Text Editor 3 and MacOS. Hence, I do not want to switch to brackets because I am happy with my current environment.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync

Comment: http://livejs.com/

Comment: Thank you @4EACH it worked fine.

Comment: Good luck @AbdullaDlshad